# Error while executing command: conda activate command on Linux EC2 instance

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, conda, aws-codebuild

I am building a build server on AWS as part of my pipeline. I am using a buildspec file, which runs the following commands after my code is copied over to the linux instance, using the image (aws/codebuild/amazonlinux2-x86_64-standard:2.0):

```
   - echo 'Install Conda to run python'
   - echo 'Download conda from web'
   - wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -O ~/miniconda.sh
   - echo 'Install miniconda'
   - sh ~/miniconda.sh -b -p $HOME/miniconda
   - eval "$(~/miniconda/bin/conda shell.bash hook)"
   - echo 'cd to outbound and list'
   - cd outbound
   - echo 'create conda environment'
   - conda env create -f environment_droplet.yml
   - conda env list
   - bash
   - conda init bash
   - echo "conda activate calme" >> ~/.bash_profile
   - echo ". ~/miniconda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" >> ~/.bash_profile
   - echo "export PATH=~/miniconda/bin:$PATH" >> ~/.bash_profile
   - . ~/.bash_profile
   - exec bash
   - conda init bash
   - conda activate calme
```

However, the last command 'conda activate  is not successful and results in the error:

```
   [Container] 2020/08/30 20:38:14 Running command conda init bash
    no change     /root/miniconda/condabin/conda
    no change     /root/miniconda/bin/conda
    no change     /root/miniconda/bin/conda-env
    no change     /root/miniconda/bin/activate
    no change     /root/miniconda/bin/deactivate
    no change     /root/miniconda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
    no change     /root/miniconda/etc/fish/conf.d/conda.fish
    no change     /root/miniconda/shell/condabin/Conda.psm1
    no change     /root/miniconda/shell/condabin/conda-hook.ps1
    no change     /root/miniconda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xontrib/conda.xsh
    no change     /root/miniconda/etc/profile.d/conda.csh
    no change     /root/.bashrc
    No action taken.
    
    [Container] 2020/08/30 20:38:14 Running command conda activate calme

CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.
To initialize your shell, run

    $ conda init <SHELL_NAME>

Currently supported shells are:
  - bash
  - fish
  - tcsh
  - xonsh
  - zsh
  - powershell

See 'conda init --help' for more information and options.

IMPORTANT: You may need to close and restart your shell after running 'conda init'.



[Container] 2020/08/30 20:38:14 Command did not exit successfully conda activate calme exit status 1
[Container] 2020/08/30 20:38:14 Phase complete: PRE_BUILD State: FAILED
[Container] 2020/08/30 20:38:14 Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: conda activate calme. Reason: exit status 1
```

As you can see, from my buildspec snippet, I am reloading the .bash_profile, applying conda init bash and creating a new bash instance too. I believed all the above commands would help reset the existing terminal, so conda activate is a recognised command - but that has not been the case.
I do not have this problem when creating a standalone EC2 instance, as I can restart the terminal / close the connection and reconnect. However, I need to be able to activate conda via the buildspec and the ec2 instance created for the build of the project. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Have you found a solution to your issue ? I've got similar one but not on EC2

Comment: Afraid not, sorry - as a work around I am not using conda on the build server - I am using python on the vm. So

Comment: that's where I ended too....